VS Code 1.89 Cannot debug C++ multiple times in a row
I am able to debug my code successfully by pressing F5, but if I attempt to run it a second time, it will fail with No such file or directory in the terminal output.
This used to work as expected, but I've started experiencing this recently, so I'm wondering if it's related to this?
My launch.json is based on the sample provided, but for reference it is this:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/test.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}

After attempting to run a second time, the terminal looks like this: Note how the second time, the start of the command seems to have been truncated
Alex@Alex_Asus MINGW64 ~/Documents/GameEngine/EngineTest
$  /usr/bin/env c:\\Users\\Alex\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.19.9-win32-x64\\debugAdapters\\bin\\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-c2axmb5z.gjq --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-5qxnf0rp.y1x --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-itnz0wk4.tmp --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-iod3xchz.rmb --dbgExe=C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe --interpreter=mi

Alex@Alex_Asus MINGW64 ~/Documents/GameEngine/EngineTest
$ ^C

Alex@Alex_Asus MINGW64 ~/Documents/GameEngine/EngineTest
$ \\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.19.9-win32-x64\\debugAdapters\\bin\\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-dob4gqtf.x31 --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-r1qtapcf.vwn --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-sysmwcem.542 --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-s2l523nn.m1i --dbgExe=C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe --interpreter=mi
bash: \ms-vscode.cpptools-1.19.9-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe: No such file or directory

Alex@Alex_Asus MINGW64 ~/Documents/GameEngine/EngineTest
$

Closing the integrated terminal and trying again works fine, but this is annoying. What am I doing wrong?

in my answer post to the question you linked, I suggested to raise an issue ticket (in the cpptools repo) if the change causes actual issues. once you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket.

Thank you, I've submitted that here

issue was closed on GH as not reproducible. voting to close for same reason here.

I managed to resolve this issue by uninstalling and re-installing vs code.
